# Reset vector of vector (2D array) to zero

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I am using vector of vector to simulate a 2D array. In order to reuse this 2D array, sometimes I need to reset all its elements to zero or some default value. I know for a simple 1D vector I can do:

```
std::fill(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
```

How to do that efficiently for a `vector<vector<int>>`? I hope to find a solution without using for loops but more akin to some `memset` variant. I also don't want to incur any memory allocation and deallocation since my intent was to reuse the existing allocated memory.

Note that I am assuming each vector's size is fixed and known to me: `vector<vector<int>> v(const_max_size, vector<int> (const_max_size, 0));`. How to reset `v`'s elements to zero?

**NOTE**: What I mean by not using `for` loops is that I don't want to iterate over all the 2D elements using subscripts like v[i][j] to assign them the value.

Comment: The storage of the inner vectors are not contiguous in memory, so there is no way you can not loop over the outer vector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I hope to find a solution without using for loops ...

Well, either you do a loop explicitly or use something that loops implicitly. Nothing wrong with explicit loops:

```
for (auto& sub : v) {
    std::fill(sub.begin(), sub.end(), 0);
}
```

I guess technically if you want to avoid a loop you could use:

```
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(),
              [](auto& sub) {
                  std::fill(sub.begin(), sub.end(), 0);
              });
```

Comment: Is `(auto& sub)` part in the lambda valid for c++11 ? or c++14? How do I check?

Comment: @Rich generic lambda are a C++14 feature

Answer (score 1):

I know I am going to get flack for this answer, but I am sure there is nothing faster:

```
for(auto& x : v) memset(&x[0],0,sizeof(int)*x.size());
```

`memset` is highly optimized for setting to 0.

Comment: did u mean `sizeof(int)*x.size()` ?

Comment: What happens if the code changes to use a different data structure?

Comment: Here's your flak jacket. :)

Comment: @NeilKirk what do you mean here? You mean what if I change my vector of vector to something else? I guess it is best to encapsulate my data structure and the desired operations into a class?

Comment: @Rich I mean this solution won't work if you change the inner vector to something else such as list, so it's not as robust.

Comment: @NeilKirk - there are always trade offs between efficiency and managing code. I agree, if code management is a priority, this is not the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the **vectors** `vector<int>` are not guaranteed to be in a contiguous block of memory, therefore one has to iterate, in whatever form, through the 1st dimension of the 2D std vector to do the reassignments.